# Swtiching X with Y on a chart made with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, openpyxl

Did anyone succeded in inverting X with Y (transpose) on a linear chart created with openpyxl ?
A workaround can be to switch x with y before represent it but im curios if openpyxl chart have this option to change x with y when represent the data

This is my code to represent the chart:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart
from openpyxl.chart import Reference
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis

wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'location of file')
ws = wb.active



c1 = LineChart()
c1.title = "aaa"
c1.style = 2
c1.y_axis.title = 'bbb'
c1.x_axis.title = 'Time'
c1.width = 40
c1.height = 20





data = Reference(ws, min_row=2, min_col=1, max_col=ws.max_column, max_row=ws.max_row)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

ws.add_chart(c1, "C28")
wb.save('location of file')
```

If this is my table:

```
      C1     C2     C3    C4          
R1            1      2     3
R2    App1   3484   323   323
R3    App2   3399   3456  323
R4    App2   323    323  3456
```

When i represent it using openpyxl chart i want to have this:

[image]

but instead, i got this:

[image]

My question is... can i easy invert them in representation without having to modify the table ?

Comment: Please add some sample data to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: hello, i have putted some photos above

Comment: Chart doesn't make a lot of sense to me but `add_data()` includes the option `from_rows` which you can use to transpose the dataset from being ordered by column to being ordered by row.

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot !!!